# While using templates: error: no matching constructor for initialization of

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

There is a namespace with `detail::RayIntersectorHits`:

```cpp
namespace detail {

    template<typename AVertexType, typename AIndexedFaceType, typename ATreeType, typename AVectorType>
    struct RayIntersector {
        using VertexType        = AVertexType;
        using IndexedFaceType   = AIndexedFaceType;
        using TreeType          = ATreeType;
        using VectorType        = AVectorType;

        const std::vector<VertexType>       &vertices;
        const std::vector<IndexedFaceType>  &faces;
        const TreeType                      &tree;

        const VectorType                     origin;
        const VectorType                     dir;
        const VectorType                     invdir;
    };

    template<typename VertexType, typename IndexedFaceType, typename TreeType, typename VectorType>
    struct RayIntersectorHits : RayIntersector<VertexType, IndexedFaceType, TreeType, VectorType> {
        std::vector<igl::Hit>                hits;
    }

}
```

I'm using `detail::RayIntersectorHits` this like this:

```cpp
template<typename VertexType, typename IndexedFaceType, typename TreeType, typename VectorType>
inline bool intersect_ray_all_hits(/* input agrs */)
{
    auto ray_intersector = detail::RayIntersectorHits<VertexType, IndexedFaceType, TreeType, VectorType> {
        vertices, faces, tree,
        origin, dir, VectorType(dir.cwiseInverse())
    };
    
    // ...
}
```

But I'm receiving this compile error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'detail::RayIntersectorHits<Matrix<float, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1>, Matrix<int, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1>, Tree<3, float>, Matrix<double, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1> >'
    auto ray_intersector = detail::RayIntersectorHits<VertexType, IndexedFaceType, TreeType, VectorType> {
                           ^                                                                             ~
```

I cannot figure out how to bypass the error. I appreciate any help.

### Resolved

The error got resolved by:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename AVertexType, typename AIndexedFaceType, typename ATreeType, typename AVectorType>
    struct RayIntersector {
        using VertexType        = AVertexType;
        using IndexedFaceType   = AIndexedFaceType;
        using TreeType          = ATreeType;
        using VectorType        = AVectorType;

        const std::vector<VertexType>       &vertices;
        const std::vector<IndexedFaceType>  &faces;
        const TreeType                      &tree;

        const VectorType                     origin;
        const VectorType                     dir;
        const VectorType                     invdir;
#ifdef CPP17_NOT_AVAILABLE
        // Aggregate initialization for the derived type is a C++17 feature
        // Trying to compile with C++14
        // If you can't upgrade to C++17 standard, you will need to define a constructor in the derived struct.
        RayIntersector(const std::vector<VertexType>        &vertices
                       , const std::vector<IndexedFaceType>     &faces
                       , const TreeType                         &tree
                       , const VectorType                    origin
                       , const VectorType                    dir
                       , const VectorType                    invdir)
            :
              vertices(vertices)
            , faces(faces)
            , tree(tree)
            , origin(origin)
            , dir(dir)
            , invdir(invdir)
        {}
#endif // CPP17_NOT_AVAILABLE
    };

    template<typename VertexType, typename IndexedFaceType, typename TreeType, typename VectorType>
    struct RayIntersectorHits : RayIntersector<VertexType, IndexedFaceType, TreeType, VectorType> {
        std::vector<igl::Hit>                hits;
#ifdef CPP17_NOT_AVAILABLE
        // Aggregate initialization for the derived type is a C++17 feature
        // Trying to compile with C++14
        // If you can't upgrade to C++17 standard, you will need to define a constructor in the derived struct.
        RayIntersectorHits(const std::vector<VertexType>        &vertices
                           , const std::vector<IndexedFaceType>     &faces
                           , const TreeType                         &tree
                           , const VectorType                    origin
                           , const VectorType                    dir
                           , const VectorType                    invdir)
            : RayIntersector<VertexType, IndexedFaceType, TreeType, VectorType>(vertices, faces, tree, origin, dir, invdir) {}
#endif // CPP17_NOT_AVAILABLE
    };
} // namespace detail
```

Comment: Also I don't see any constructor, you should initialize the structure with {}, please provide the full 'uncommented' code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined an aggregate struct which does not have any user-defined constructors. You can initialize `struct RayIntersector` with [aggregate initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
struct A
{
    public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B: public A
{
    int c;
};

void func()
{
    auto varA = A{1,2};   // Compiles with C++14
    auto varB = B{2,3,4}; // Compiles with C++17
}
```

But aggregate initialization for the derived type is a C++17 feature:

> The effects of aggregate initialization are:
>
> > Each direct public base, (since C++17) array element, or non-static class member, in
> > order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition is copy-initialized from
> > the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

If you can't upgrade to C++17 standard, you will need to define a constructor in the derived struct.